# Scene three js remains definitively blank, impossible to create a project

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a big problem, I don't understand why I can't use three js. I've been trying different ways to use three js for a few days now, but to no avail. I first tried parcel by creating a new porjet. Then I quickly turned to bender vite. The installation went perfectly here are all the commands I typed in my terminal:

npm create vite@latest ( vanilla, javascript )
npm install
npm add three
npm run dev

Then when I go to my project folder, I have folders: node_modules, public. files: .gitgnore, idnex.html, javascript.svg, main,js, package-lock.json, package.json, style.css
I didn't touch anything in the files and folders. There's a three folder and a quick one in node_modules.

Here's the code I put in main.js :

```
import { Scene, WebGLRenderer } from 'three';
import './style.css';

const scene = new Scene();
const renderer = new WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(widnow.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

My code editor, between 'from' and 'three' on the first line, writes :
Could not find a declaration file for module 'three'. c:/Users/cerng/Desktop/Three/particles/node_modules/three/build/three.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Here's what's in the .json package:

{
"name": "particles",
"private": true,
"version": "0.0.0",
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
"dev": "vite",
"build": "vite build",
"preview": "vite preview"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@types/three": "^0.160.0",
"vite": "^5.0.8"
},
"dependencies": {
"three": "^0.160.0"
}
}

The code I've written should display a completely black scene, but it remains white ( I use chrome and I've tried it on edge )

I tried uninstalling three.js and then reinstalling it.
Run this command: npm install --save-dev @types/three.
I've also tried the solutions proposed on the other posts, but their problems aren't quite the same.

Comment: From your code it looks like you are only creating scene, but not putting anything on screen. As for your question it would help if you get answers if you shorten it.

Comment: You will need to look at your browser's dev tools to see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have typo

```
renderer.setSize(widnow.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
```

Switch on:

```
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
```

…moreover call `render` method with parameters: `scene` and `camera`.

```
renderer.render(scene, camera)
```